# Extending Graphics Void to Jframe?

Tags: java, graphic

I have Jframe Form and created class to draw graphics from it, and for to do that i need to extend that void class to jframe form

```
package grafiktest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class testoutput extends javax.swing.JFrame{
Graphics g;

public testoutput() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    g=jPanel1.getGraphics();
test tod = new test(); 
tod.test();

}
```

class i created :

```
     public class test extends testoutput{
     void test(){ 
      testoutput tod = new testoutput(); 
      g=tod.jPanel1.getGraphics();
   g.setColor(Color.decode("#7D9AB3"));
    g.fillRect(3,3,3,3);
   }
    }
```

is there any way to extend it?
I'm newb for this, Thank you

Comment: How do you want to extend it? You should work on your formatting / classname standards.

Comment: Okay - first, STOP - this is NOT how custom painting should be performed.  Go and read through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for a better understanding of how painting works and what you need to do to incorporate into it

Comment: To answer your question - no, this is not "how" you would do it.  `testoutput` should calls some method which `test` can then override in order to inject it's functionality

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring your bad painting for the time been, you should start by taking a closer look at the [Inheritance trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) which will provide you with more information.

In short, no, this is not how inheritance works.

I appreciate that this can be confusing and I highly recommend you simplify your example by taking `JFrame` out of the picture and seeing how the operations might work

Let's start with simple enough example...

```
public class Parent {

    public Parent() {
        //...
    }

    public void performSomeAction() {
        System.out.println("I'm called from within parent");
    }
}
```

And some child class

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void performSomeAction() {
        // Action overridden from parent
        // You can call super.performSomeAction()
        // if you wish to maintain the functionality the parent class was
        // performing as needed
        System.out.println("I'm called from within child");
    }

}
```

Now, let's have a look at what happens if we do...

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child();

parent.performSomeAction();
child.performSomeAction();
```

This outputs...

```
I'm called from within parent
I'm called from within child
```

Not very exciting, but you get the idea.

But, wait, lets change `Child`

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void performSomeAction() {
        super.performSomeAction()
        System.out.println("I'm called from within child");
    }

}
```

Now, if we re-run the test code, we get

```
I'm called from within parent
I'm called from within parent
I'm called from within child
```

Where did the extra "parent" call come from!?  It comes from `super.performSomeAction()`, this simply calls the parent's method - this is how overriding a method can be used to extend it's functionality or even completely overwrite (as was done in the first example).

Now, lets do something really weird...

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Parent child = new Child();

parent.performSomeAction();
child.performSomeAction();
```

What do you suppose the output will be?!

I'll leave it up to you to test, but you might also want to then have a look at [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) and be prepared to be

And finally...Go and read through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for a better understanding of how painting works and what you need to do to work with it